Dimensions of C (250, 286) should be one smaller than X(251) and Y(287) while using shading='flat'
Im trying to make a function which would create a spectrogram using audiosegment, create a graph using matplotlib.plot and save it as an image, however, i keep getting the error in the title. I understand that the list C of the pcolormesh function needs to be smaller than the X and Y but that should be the case, as it literally says it in the error.
this is the code:
import os 
import shutil
import audiosegment
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def spectrogram(file, output_dir):
    seg = audiosegment.from_file(file)
    freqs, times, amplitudes = seg.spectrogram(window_length_s=0.03, overlap=0.5)
    amplitudes = 10 * np.log10(amplitudes + 1e-9)
    times_new = np.resize(times, times.size + 1)
    freqs_new = np.resize(freqs, freqs.size + 1)
    print(len(times))
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
    plt.pcolormesh(times_new, freqs_new, amplitudes, shading='auto')
    plt.title("spectrogram " + file.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0])
    plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
    plt.ylabel("Frequency [Hz]")
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(output_dir, "spectrogram_" + file.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]))
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()

I have also tried resizing the numpy array without cretaing a new one like this:
times = np.append(times, times[-1] + (times[-1] - times[-2]))
freqs = np.append(freqs, freqs[-1] + (freqs[-1] - freqs[-2]))
...
plt.pcolormesh(times, freqs, amplitudes, shading='auto')


Let's start with a minimal reproducible example. We don't have your audio files, and, moreover, we don't really need them: the question is about pcolormesh; we don't really care here that the data come from audio or something else
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

times=np.linspace(0, 1, 251)
freqs=np.linspace(0, 22050, 287)
amplitudes = 1+np.sin(freqs[None,1:]*1e-4)+times[1:,None]

print(times.shape, freqs.shape, amplitudes.shape)

Shows
(251,) (287,) (250, 286)

So, we have our MRE.
We can easily get the same error
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
plt.pcolormesh(times, freqs, amplitudes, shading='auto')

⇒
TypeError: Dimensions of C (250, 286) should be one smaller than X(251) and Y(287) while using shading='flat' see help(pcolormesh)


That is because colormesh takes 3 2d-array as argument. X and Y, describing the X and Y coordinates of the 251×287 points of the grid. And C, is a 250×286 array, describing the colors of the 250x286 cells delimited by that grid
a 3×3 points grids creates a 2x2 cells
A---B---C   <— 1
| α | β |
D---E---F   <— 2 
| γ | δ |
G---H---I   <— 3

^   ^   ^
|   |   |
1   2   3

Here, we have 9 points (3x3) [[A,B,C],[D,E,F],[G,H,I]], so 3x3 X coordinates: [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], and 3×3 Y coordinates [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]], delimiting 4 (2x2) cells, α, β, γ, δ, so 2x2 colors [[α,β],[γ,δ]]
If you pass 1D array [1,2,3] as X, and 1D array [1,2,3] as Y, pcolormesh doesn't know what to do with it.
(Nothing says that on each rows, those coordinates are the same. Nothing says that each cells are just aligned horizontal squares)
Fortunately, there is a function to create a regular mesh from 2 1D array.
Y,X=np.meshgrid(freqs, times)
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, amplitudes, shading='auto')


Note that I am not sure of what is the shapes of your times and freqs in your example.
But that x coordinates of the graph correspond to the 2nd axis (axis 1), while y coordinates to the first (axis 0).
So length of times is 251, and length of freqs is 287, then the 2nd dimension of amplitude should be 250, and the first dimension of amplitude should be 286.
So, pragmatically, in addition to what I've described (meshgrid), you may need to use amplitudes.T rather than amplitude, or to inverse times and freqs) to get what you want.
